# Using Angular 1.5 - Can you have a component inside another component's template?

Tags: angularjs, components, angularjs-1.5

New to angular 1.5 and trying to better understand component communication. Wondering if I can have a component inside another component's template? And if so, how do they communicate with one another (using require?)?

Comment: This question is to broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Each component has inputs and outputs. Inputs are from the parent to child, whereas outputs are from child to parent. In this [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Unw34BquGR9Mmv2Rz6Wp?p=preview), the actual value increment is done in the parent component's controller, yet the value is displayed in the child component, where the increment button is.

```
.component('parentComponent', {
    template: '<child-component value="$ctrl.value" on-increment="$ctrl.increment()"></child-component>',
    controller: function() {
      // Init
      var self = this;
      self.$onInit = function() {
      //
      }
      self.value = 7;

      // Increment
      self.increment = function() {
        return self.value += 1;
      }
    },
    bindings: {
      //
    }
})
.component('childComponent', {
    template: '<h2 ng-bind="$ctrl.value"></h2><button ng-click="$ctrl.onIncrement()">Increment Value</button>',
    controller: function() {},
    bindings: {
      value: '<',
      onIncrement: '&'
    }
});
```